# Floating windows/sticky notes that always stay in the front on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, python, sticky-notes

I am using windows 10, I would like to create small sticky notes or floating windows which will always stay in the front of other applications/windows. I have tried multiple apps on Microsoft app but none works. Are there any recommended apps I can try?

I am also a Python programmer, if there is a way to create a floating window using Python, I can also try it.